# Odd Try/Catch Behavior

Tags: c#, oracle, exception

I have a simple try/catch block

```
try
{
     // Open the connection
     _connection.Open(); // [1]
}
catch( OracleException ex ) // [2]
{
     // Handle the exception
     int x = ex.ErrorCode;
}
```

The catch is never executed and the runtime reports 'OracleException was unhandled' at [1] which just makes my head spin. Clearly, I have a catch statement for the associated exception type. I've even tried the fully qualified type, Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException at [2] and still the exception is unhandled.

The only way I can actually get the catch to work is by catching System.Exception at [2]. What is causing this odd behavior?

Comment: When you catch `Exception` what is printed when you write `ex.GetType().ToString()`?

Comment: It sounds like the OracleException is being wrapped in a different type of Exception. What does the full stack trace say?

Comment: When caught as Exception, it returns, "Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException"

Comment: So it looks like you either need to type out the complete name of the exception or catch a more general version such as `DbException` which is the base ADO.NET exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you dynamically loading assemblies at all, possibly using `Assembly.LoadFrom` or something similar? If so, you might be hitting a situation where the type that you have mutiple types loaded into different load contexts.

Assemblies loaded into different context present the same types with different identities so they do not match type equality checks etc.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28.aspx)

- The load context contains assemblies
  found by probing: in the GAC, in a
  host assembly store if the runtime is
  hosted, or in the ApplicationBase and
  PrivateBinPath of the application
  domain. Most overloads of the Load
  method load assemblies into this
  context.
- The load-from context contains
  assemblies for which the user
  provided a path not included in the
  directories searched by probing.
  LoadFrom, CreateInstanceFrom, and
  ExecuteAssembly are examples of
  methods that load by path.

Of course this is just a guess, so I might be wrong.

Comment: Sounds like you and I had the same theory.

Comment: This is a great suggestion, I'm going to check the GAC. I know that I have workstation has two version of the Oracle ODP client installed. I bet there is an issue.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is throwing an Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException instead of an Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException . I know it sounds odd, but it is possible to have two types with exactly the same name loaded into a given AppDomain.

Try this...

```
try 
{ 
     // Open the connection 
     _connection.Open(); // [1] 
} 
catch( Exception ex ) // [2] 
{ 
     if (ex.GetType() == typeof(OracleException)) Debug.WriteLine("is match");
     else Debug.WriteLine ("is not match");

     // Handle the exception 
     int x = ex.ErrorCode; 
}
```

Another possibility is that the exception is wrapped. You may be getting an InvalidOperationException that contains a OracleException.

Finally, the error may just be just after your try block. Either you misread the stack trace or the line numbers in the stack trace are wrong. Both happen to me all the time.

Comment: Stupid C# and its lack of spell checking. I don't know why it doesn't take care of such things for me like VB does. (Which is odd itself because VB's compiler doesn't care how you capitalize keywords.)

Comment: I think you and Chris are on the right track. I realize earlier I had an error from an InvalidCastException say it could not cast Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException to Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException. To me that seems like there is a version issue right?

Comment: great suggestion, wish I could pick two correct answers. You and Chris had the right idea. Two types of the same name loaded! Issue fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to catch the more general `DbException`.

```
try
{
     // Open the connection
     _connection.Open(); // [1]
}
catch( DbException ex ) // [2]
{
     // Handle the exception
     int x = ex.ErrorCode;
}
```